# Apache: minimization with bounds and constraints

Tags: apache, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I am currently testing Apache library for optimisation Non linear problems (with Non linear least squared method). 
I have implemented a class based on Levenberg Marquardt solution. 
But I have noticed that LM in Apache does not allow boundaries when looking for the optimal solution. It means that my optimum point is a unfeasible solution.
How to deal with it in Apache?
Just tried to find another in Apache method but it was unsuccessful.

In the same time, What are the best solutions in Apache to deal with boundaries and constraints for a non linear least squared method. I mean for example if I have 4 variables and I want to get a specific relationship between these variables. Let's say a definite semi positive correlation matrix for example.

Thanks in advance for your tips